# Input 2 XML files to produce a combined CSV output in JAVA

Tags: java, xml, xpath

I have 2 xml files (one around 50 MB and other one 120K) which can be linked using a common field. I need to read the files, link them on the common field and produce a combined output in CSV. 
Can someone please advise what would be the most efficient way to do that using JAVA ?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a good example to look at ( http://www.developerfusion.com/code/2064/a-simple-way-to-read-an-xml-file-in-java/ ).  You will have to tweak it some, but the point of the example shows you how to gain access to the file (in your case, files) and then processing each parent node, you can get the child nodes and do your processing, then write out a CSV.  Let me know if you need more information or get stuck.